# Какие данные должны отправляться на сервер(best practices) при регистрации через Google или Facebook

Tags: java, android

Уже был подобный вопрос, но я хотел бы уточнить у разработчиков которые реализовывали LogIn через facebook или Google.

Я планирую реализовать так: если юзер получает разрешение от этих сетей, то я беру его почту как уникальный идентификатор и отправляю его на сервер для регистрации.

- Нужно ли что то еще для идентификации юзера, чтоб не столкнуться с
  подводными камнями при дальнейшей работе?

И вопрос насчет того как быть если юзер сделал регистрацию через facebook, а потом купил себе телефон и пытается зайти через стандартную форму логин-пароль. Сервер никак не сможет распознать этого юзера так как он делал регистрацию через facebook.

Насколько мне удалось выяснить возможно 2 способа решения :

1. При регистрации юзера через сети, после того как мы получаем доступ
   к аккаунту попросить создать пароль для его аккаунта в нашем
   приложении и таким образом у нас будет почта которую мы получим с
   аккаунта и пароль который юзер введет для регистрации и в будущем мы
   сможем его распознать не только через ту форму регистрации через
   которую он ее сделал, а и через стандартную(логин + пароль).
2. Второе возможное решение это когда юзер пытается войти в аккаунт
   через логин/пароль предварительно зарегистрировавшись через сети мы
   проверяем его почту и сервер возвращает сообщение юзеру, извените но
   этот майл адрес был зарегистрирован через facebook, пожалуйста
   войдите использую эту возможность.

Как было бы лучше реализовать это со стороны практичности что ли... ?